# Setting type of ObservableList when using a custom class and Comparator

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to sort a list of a custom class extending HBox inside a VBox. Everything is working perfectly leaving out the type declarations but I was wondering if there was a way to get rid of the warnings.

```
public static class FilePane extends HBox {}    

public void sort() {
    int order = orderBy.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    Comparator<FilePane> comp = null;
    if(order == 0) {
        comp = Comparator.comparing(FilePane::getFileNameLower);
    } else if(order == 1) {
        comp = Comparator.comparingLong(FilePane::getFileDate);
        comp = comp.reversed();
    } else if(order == 2) {
        comp = Comparator.comparingLong(FilePane::getFileSize);
        comp = comp.reversed();
    } else if(order == 3) {
        comp = Comparator.comparingLong(FilePane::getFileCount);
        comp = comp.reversed();
    } else if(order == 4) {
        comp = Comparator.comparing(FilePane::getDirectory);
        comp = comp.reversed();
    }
    ObservableList list = fileList.getChildren();
    FXCollections.sort(list, comp);
}
```

Trying to set `list` to `ObservableList<FilePane>` gives an error telling me it should be set to `<Node>` since that's what `getChildren()` returns. Setting it to `<Node>` does not work and `FXCollections.sort(list, comp);` gives an error that FilePane will not work because:

```
The method sort(ObservableList<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type FXCollections is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList<Node>, Comparator<FilePane>)
```

FilePane extends HBox which should be considered a Node? Comparator's type can't be set to Node because it needs to have the class to compare with. Casting with `ObservableList<FilePane> list = (ObservableList<FilePane>) fileList.getChildren();` tells me that it can't do that so it isn't an option.

Should I just ignore the type warnings since it works fine without them? Is there a way to set the VBox's children to a `ObservableList<FilePane>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getChildren()` returns a list of `Node`s, then you need the list to be a list of `Node`s. Let's start there and work backwards.

```
ObservableList<Node> list = fileList.getChildren();
```

Okay. If that's the list, then how do we get the `sort()` call to compile? The answer is that the comparator must be a `Comparator<Node>` and not a `Comparator<FilePane>`.

But that's no good, right? Because then we can't use those really slick `FilePane::` method references. Hold on there, partner. Not so fast. Isn't there some way to leave that code alone and still make `sort()` happy?

There is. Let's leave `comp` alone. It can stay as a `Comparator<FilePane>`. What we need to do is convert it into a `Comparator<Node>` some how.

```
FXCollections.sort(list, convertSomeHow(comp));
```

How do we convert it? Well, `sort()` is going to pass the comparator `Node`s. The comparator we have wants `FilePane`s. So all we need to do is get a cast in there and then defer to `comp`. Something like this:

```
FXCollections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(node -> (FilePane) node, comp));
```

Or:

```
FXCollections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(FilePane.class::cast, comp));
```

Comment: Thanks! I used the first choice using the lambda and the warnings went away.